# Flot yaxis label is not showing

Tags: jquery, label, flot

I could not figure out why the yaxis label is not displaying. I am using Mark Cote's jquery.flot.axislabels.js. Could someone please help me to take a look following code?

```
options = {
    series: {
        lines:  { show: true, lineWidth: 1 },
        points: { show: pshow, radius: 2 },
        color: cnum
    },
    legend: {
        position: "nw",
        backgroundOpacity: 0.5
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: timeformat,
        timezone: "utc"
    },
    yaxis: {
        ticks: 15,
        tickDecimals: 3,
        minTickSize: 1,
        axisLabel: 'Milliseconds',
        axisLabelPadding: 10,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 10
    },
    grid: { hoverable: true },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%x.1 - %y.4",
        shifts: { x: -60, y: 25 }
    },
    selection: { mode: "xy" }
};

var plot = $.plot(placeholder, rdata.data, options);
```

"rdata.data" contains multiple series. I tried to plot only one and it did not help.

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that replicates the issue?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ax6wW/1/, you'll have to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I figured out the problem. I had the plugins as follow, which caused the problem.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/flot/jquery.flot.js'></script>
```

As soon as I flapped the order, it worked beautifully.